# I am getting this issue after I upload Translatepress plugin. everything is smooth when real language but problem when translate into German

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, translate

I am getting this issue after I upload Translatepress plugin. everything is smooth when is its in real language but have problem shows below when change in to German

Warning
: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '!' in
/homepages/2/d909770871/htdocs/clickandbuilds/Neffisso/wp-content/plugins/opal-widgets-for-elementor/includes/class-woo-elementor.php
on line
109

Please help me why is this so

Comment: go to that line 109,  it should be something like this: `preg_match($pattern, $string, $match);` then try to change it to this: `preg_match(preg_quote ($pattern), $string, $match);`. If it does not help then you need to provide contents of  `$pattern`

Answer (score 0):

That’s because you have a RegEx there that is incorrectly set OR the string you’ve added is having characters that interfere with preg_match(). In fact, I was under the impression that these kinds of errors are ignored. It’s harmless anyway, it’s just filling the debug.log, that’s all.

There is almost similar problem and solution https://wordpress.org/support/topic/preg_match-unknown-modifier-f/

Thank you